# Define order of factor data

Tags: r, sorting

I am struggling to modify the order of my factor data. Using the mtcars dataset as example, I am using the following code to order the data by 'cyl'.

```
library(dplyr)
arrange (mtcars, cyl)
```

This orders the data as cyl=4, 6, 8, respectively, but how can I change this order to be 4, 8, 6, respectively? I tried `sort`, using `c(4, 8, 6)`, but no luck. There must be some easy solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to define `cyl` as `factor` with `levels` based on our preference and then use `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c(4, 8, 6))) %>%
  arrange(cyl)
```

Same using base R would be

```
df <- transform(mtcars, cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c(4, 8, 6)))
df[order(df$cyl), ]
```

---

Or another option is to use `match` and then `order`

```
mtcars[order(match(mtcars$cyl, c(4, 8, 6))), ]
```

Comment: In my opinion this should be done using `ordered` or `factor(..., ordered=TRUE)` rather than relying on an implicit order. Particularly relevant if you try to do calculations - `max(factor(1:3))` versus `max(ordered(1:3))`

Comment: @thelatemail hmmm..I haven't used `ordered` and also from your example I understand the benefit of `ordered=TRUE` in `factor` but since the question is about ordering rows do you think this would be any different/beneficial than the `factor` which I have used.

Comment: @RonakShah - Thank you so much. That's terrific!

Comment: @RonakShah - I think it's beneficial in that it has basically no overhead, just changing `factor` to `ordered`, but then opens up the possibility of using `max`, `min`, comparison functions `>` `>=` etc with the result. There's nothing *wrong* with using `factor`, but `ordered` seems *more right* to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[order(factor(cyl, levels = c(4, 8, 6)))]
```